# Can we create a class from a xml file?

Tags: java, design-patterns, oop, object

Is it possible to create a class dynamically by reading an xml file  ( in java preferably) ? if yes, please provide  pointers on how to do it.

In the process of development, we have come up with a class that has 5 attributes, all these attributes correspond to an entry in the xml file, now if the user adds/modifies the xml entry the object corresponding to it must change automatically, one approach would be generate the source code, before compile time.Is there any other way ?

Is there any common pattern to model such changes in the system ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an XML Schema for your XML there are a number of kits for this. Start with JAX-B.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I am going through it. Just before I get through the entire doc, I had a quick question : At present, I already have a static class declaration that is used across the module, what will JAX-B do for me ? will it replace the static compile time class with the one it generates at runtime ?

Thanks

Comment: You can either tell JAXB to generate a Java source file from an XSD, or the other way around, or you can mess around with @annotations until they converge.

Answer (score 1):

If you stored your attributes in a HashMap then you could simply parse the XML and then set the attributes accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a XML schema (xsd), you can feed that schema to JAXB's [xjc](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxb/xjc.html) command to generate Java classes.  xjc is included with the Java 6 JDK.

Answer (score 0):

The process usually works the other way around (ie. defining a class with those attributes, and serializing an instance of the class to XML)

If you really need that sort of flexibility, a scripting language would save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I think [JAX-B](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/tutorial/) can provide functionality like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for byte code generation, have a look at [cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/), it is the one used in Hibernate.

But maybe some annotations can also fulfill your requirement, just like Google Guice's dependency injection.